# .NetFramework 4 on Windows 2003 Server with IIS6

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have a website for .net-framework 3.5 with WebForms
I am running it on two servers Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS7.5
And Windows 2003 Server with IIS6

On IIS7.5, when I run my website under .NetFramework 3.5 or 4, it runs fine.
On IIS6, when I run my website under .NetFramework 3.5 it works fine, but when I run it under 4.0, I get 404 errors and site doesn't work.

What could be wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
cscript c:\windows\system32\iisext.vbs /EnFile C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

After executing this your .NET 4 apps shouldn't show any 404 errors anymore... Windows 2003 should at least have SP1 installed for this...

Comment: it enables the aspnet 4 ISAPI dll in IIS (for some obscure reason it doesn't get enabled by the installer of NET 4), after that line you need to restart IIS...